# Program freezes when playing video with hardware acceleration

Tags: windows-7, video, graphics-card, amd-radeon, hardware-acceleration

When I watch video online (flash) or locally (any type), the video screen turns green and then freezes after a few seconds.

It'll be fine if I disable `hardware acceleration`.

**This only happens recently, it was all good before.** I'v tried to re-install my system and updated to the latest driver, but the problem is still there. I'm wondring if anything goes wrong with my video card?

Windows Device Manager says: Device status: This device is working properly.

Is there a third party program that can check for video card problem and health?

Spec:

Windows 7 64-bit
ATI Radeon 4890

Comment: How are you disabling hardware acceleration for local video playback?

Answer (score 0):

If graph card has power socket, maybe it is not connected. not all motherboards can give much power from itself to graph card.